# Angular universal Seo tags and JSON LD Issue.. Rendering one time on reload the page, meta and schema hides

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-seo

Basically i am working on angular universal . In this i set and add the meta tags and add schema. And when we run the build (npm run build:ssr and npm run serve:ssr) . It sometimes show the meta and schema and some time hides. But static schema are shown all the time. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue and i doesnot get any help from anywhere.

Package.json code

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run abc:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.2.6",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "v8.2.6",
    "angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.3-alpha1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.12",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lazysizes": "^5.2.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-json-ld": "^0.3.1",
    "ngx-plyr": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.1.0",
    "plyr": "^3.5.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "sticky-sidebar": "^3.3.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any error in the console server side?

Comment: no error related to meta tags. Secondly @David i resolve all the errors in console. Some broken images error is there now. I think that will not effect the SSR

Comment: When you don't have the meta, are the components in the page all rendered properly server side? Any error, even not related to meta, could cause rendering to stop and so meta would not be added

Comment: Basically All the meta tags are rendering properly only meta and schema giving issues. When we do Ctrl + Shift +r atleast 3-4 times it reset to default meta which was in index.html. I remove all the data from console.

Process to show meta ------> make the function of meta in the service and call that function and pass parameter into that function and call when api gives response data in ngoninit